# How do I do that cool show desktop thing in gnome?

Tags: gnome, compiz

I've just started using GNOME for my main desktop environment and I was answering the phone and when I came back to my computer the windows all flew around the screen like I was on some kinda freakin mac.  That was pretty cool, but I don't know what I did to make it happen. I think all I did was move the mouse.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably accidentally hit a compiz keyboard shortcut. There is a list [here](http://helpforlinux.blogspot.com/2008/09/complete-list-of-compiz-keyboard.html) if you want to try and replicate it.

I think one of these are what you're talking about:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yeah, the 3rd one I have happen to me pretty much at random.  Running Fedora though.