# Program meta/win key for compiz

Tags: linux, keyboard, compiz

I've got an IBM Model I, sans winkey.  I'd like to use some of the cool compiz features, is there any way for me to program a windows key?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/19698/how-do-i-do-that-cool-show-desktop-thing-in-gnome/19699#19699   This is why I'm asking.

Comment: More accurate would be "Program meta/win key for Compiz", I don't have the rep to change it myself.

Comment: I might as well change it and accept your answer, still would be cool to know how to program it for GNOME as well.

Comment: as far as key-bindings you can over-ride any of them, you just need to know where to look to do so. What gnome keybinding do you know of that requires the meta/win key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install **compizconfig-settings-manager** and you should be able to override any of the key bindings very easily.

```
$ sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

You can modify any gnome bindings to your liking by going to:

**System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**